# Fresh Install Linux Firefox Cannot Sync

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I recently fresh installed Ubuntu, and Firefox cannot seem to sync. There is no pop up error message of any sort.

I've tried logging out and in again my Firefox account, but none of anything which can be synced is synced.

For example, I installed Lockwise on my Android and can see all my saved login credentials, I cannot see any on my new Firefox on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting `.mozilla` directory and try re-sync. But this time, it synced back my fresh installed Firefox, including just a few passwords I've typed in, (like my Firefox account credentials).

I managed to find my `.mozilla` from my backup drive and replaced the fresh installed one instead. This isn't exactly a solution for everyone. But it was my solution.

Still I have no idea why I can have more than one profile on Firefox's server under just 1 account. There is no indication of that on Firefox Account.